# How to block specific websites for certain users in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am prone to procrastination and am trying to make a second user account on my windows 10 desktop with facebook youtube etc blocked. I tried setting the sites I want blocked to 127.0.0.1 in my etc\hosts file but I still want to be able to access those sites on my main account. I tried looking at ways to create a sort of user-specific hosts file and I realize there are programming workarounds to accomplish this but I don't have enough of a programming background to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two users with two profiles: Make two scripts ('batch files') with a text editor such as Notepad. Each changes the file *C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts* depending on whether you are in Slack mode or Work mode.

In a Command Prompt Window, take your existing **hosts** file in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\ and copy it to **hosts.old** **hosts.work**  and **hosts.slack** (names can be changed to collect the innocent). Making **hosts.old** is a safety measure.

The **hosts.work** file is then edited to add the sites which you want to block and directs them to 127.0.0.1 so they are inaccessible.

Batch file "A" ,"SLACK.BAT", copies **hosts.slack** to **hosts** . It should be placed in the Path, perhaps into c:\windows\system 32, and then a shortcut created on the desktop to it for the sake of convenience.

```
echo off  
rem SLACK.BAT  
C:
cd \Windows\System32\Drivers\etc
copy hosts.slack hosts
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Batch file "B", "WORK.BAT", copies **hosts.old* to **hosts.work**. 
It should be placed in the Path, perhaps into c:\windows\system 32, and then a shortcut created on the desktop to it for the sake of convenience.

```
echo off  
rem WORK.BAT  
C:
cd \Windows\System32\Drivers\etc
copy hosts.work hosts
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I have zero programming knowledge. I have an idea of what batch file are/ what they do but I have no clue how to actually write them. I do like learning new things and it seems like it could be quite useful so do you have any resources that you could point me towards to learn how to do what you suggested?

Comment: Both `.bat` files should end with `ipconfig /flushdns` to remove any cached DNS entries.