# Can someone help me understand the answer to another post? It is related to making scripts in order to block websites for a work profile

Tags: batch-file, windows-11

I really want to understand what is written, because I sometimes have the same question as the person who is asking as well as to learn more. I tried searching for certain terms, but I ended more confused. So sorry if the answer to the question should be obvious, I still want to ask my questions.

My question is similar to the question that I found on this website here: [How to block specific websites for certain users in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1532584/how-to-block-specific-websites-for-certain-users-in-windows-10)

From what I understand. The answer seems to be really what I want. Switching between a work mode and "slack"/ not work mode with some shortcuts. So I wanted to try it out. But I got stuck at the first step.

**The first step is: Make two scripts ('batch files') with a text editor such as Notepad. Each changes the file C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts depending on whether you are in Slack mode or Work mode.**

I have searched how to make batch files and i learned that I simply needed to save a notepad doc with .bat behind it. So I made the "work.bat" file and "slack.bat" file like the answerer mentioned (but without capital letters, is that needed?). They are still empty and are in my downloads folder because I thought that I needed to do the next step first:

**In a Command Prompt Window, take your existing hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\ and copy it to hosts.old hosts.work and hosts.slack (names can be changed to collect the innocent). Making hosts.old is a safety measure.**

I tried opening Command Prompt Window by typing cmd in my searchbar. And then i got stuck. I have been able to find the "etc" folder, not using cmd, but that using file explorer (sorry I am not using English system, so maybe wrong name). I did not understand what it meant to copy my existing hosts file to hosts.old, hosts.work and hosts.slack. Because I did not have a hosts.old, host.work or host.slack file (I have made a copy of the original hosts file in the etc folder and put it in a new folder, so maybe I can make that one hosts.old somehow). And even if I did, do I just open the hosts file, copy its contents and then open the hosts.work file to paste it in?

Should I make the 3 files myself in the etc folder? If yes, do i need to use the Command Prompt Window to do that OR using the .bat files OR should I make the files using the etc folder found with file explorer?

**The hosts.work file is then edited to add the sites which you want to block and directs them to 127.0.0.1 so they are inaccessible.**

I think that I know how to do this. I saw a video saying that I can run notepad as administrator and go to the etc folder and edit the file.

**Batch file "A" ,"SLACK.BAT", copies hosts.slack to hosts . It should be placed in the Path, perhaps into c:\windows\system 32, and then a shortcut created on the desktop to it for the sake of convenience.**

```
echo off  
rem SLACK.BAT  
C:
cd \Windows\System32\Drivers\etc
copy hosts.slack hosts
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Batch file "B", "WORK.BAT", copies hosts.old* to **hosts.work. It should be placed in the Path, perhaps into c:\windows\system 32, and then a shortcut created on the desktop to it for the sake of convenience. (the answerer used * and ** here, making it bold caused some trouble, so I am not bolding this part)

```
echo off  
rem WORK.BAT  
C:
cd \Windows\System32\Drivers\etc
copy hosts.work hosts
ipconfig /flushdns
```

I think that this is what I should put in my .bat files, but I am not certain so i will ask it here. Do I put the first code in slack.bat and the second code in work.bat? If it copies "host.old" to hosts.work, does that mean that all the sites i wanted to block that I have to put in hosts.work will be replaced by hosts.old? If yes, then does that mean that I have to write the sites I want to block everytime?

Comment: Have you tried either of these scripts?

Comment: https://getcoldturkey.com/

Comment: The first paragraph of that guide is an overview of what will happen. The actions start with the 2nd paragraph. You don't HAVE to use CMD to copy and rename your hosts file, but some may find that easier. The Hosts file is hidden (for good reason) and you'll need to learn how to view hidden files. The instructions to "copy" mean that you are creating backups and copies of the hosts file that the two scripts will act upon to set the different network settings for work and slack.

Comment: But, due to your lack of familiarity with the technical aspects of this, Gandendo's suggestion is likely a better choice for you. Use a tool that does this for you more simply.

Comment: @Gantendo Thank you this seems very useful

Comment: @music2myear Thank you. I had already found the original hosts file. In the etc folder and selecting "all files". But I could not find the hosts.slack and hosts.work files that the answerer mentioned. So I thought that I should ask how I can get them or make them.

Comment: @Ramhound I have just tried it. I saw something open and close very quickly. It seemed similar to the cmd screen. Maybe i need to make the hosts.work and hosts.slack files first. But I am trying to figure out how to do that. And thank you for editing my question

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to make hosts.work and hosts.slack files in the etc folder by copying the hosts file and renaming them. After that, I tried to edit the hosts.work file. Writing 127.0.0.1 and the website adres as a test like how people block sites using the normal hosts file (in video they use no .work or.slack, but they don't make profiles). 

After saving, I double clicked work.bat. And then i opened the test site in another browser. It did not seem to block the site. I went to check and the normal hosts file does not have the 127.0.0.1 and site adres.

Comment: @Ramhound I also saw that it is saved as a WORK-file instead of a normal file like the normal "hosts" file. Do you know if that is supposed to happen?

Comment: Windows blithely ignores the *hosts* for their own sites, and others: https://petri.com/windows-10-ignoring-hosts-file-specific-name-resolution/ . It might be necessary to add **firewall rules**, https://techviral.net/block-websites-using-firewall-windows-11/ , though rule only applies to an IP address, not the URL.

Comment: You are running the script as an Administrator?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for the late reply and thank you. I tried running it as an administrator and it worked! The site from hosts.work was added to hosts. I tried adding another site to hosts.work and after saving and rerunning as administrator that worked as well. I then tested switching between work and slack and that worked as well. So I think that I have finally learned how to make a work and slack profile. Thank you and everyone else that helped

Comment: Everyone thank you for helping me. I have been able to use the scripts and can now make a work and slack profile! After thinking some more, I can't exactly say that I have learned how to do it myself. Because I just copied the script from 
K7AAY without even understanding it 100%. But I am still happy to learn more and that I can use the profiles. Maybe I will learn about it in the future.

By the way, does someone know if I have to mark my question as answered? And if yes, where can I find the button for that?